# Android - Mask/Layer on ImageView

Tags: android, animation, imageview, mask, objectanimator

I need to create a BLACK mask on an ImageView which is a mellon (like a circle) and I need to put on that mask an animation (property animation using ObjectAnimator) in order to change the alpha of the mask, and then the imageview should be shown properly. So:
- black mask shaped as a circle, over a mellon, and that mask should be able to change it's alpha from 1.0 to 0.0.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you able to use a canvas?

Comment: I don't know how to do the mask. I need some example. I have searched and I have not found any good answer.

Comment: I would like to get the shape of the mellon, turn it into black, and then use it as a mask (which will go from 1.0 to 0.0 alpha).